# Useful third-party Object-C GUI add-ons for iPhone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, add-on

When I develop in .NET there's lots of UI controls from companies like Infragistics and Telerik that enable me to build above-and-beyond standard usability and stylish GUIs rapidly.  Is there anything like that for iPhone Objective-C development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the venerable and lauded [three20](http://github.com/blog/389-three20-iphone-ui-goodness) library, but some might be concerned about use of private frameworks, which will get your app rejected.

Answer (score 1):

May become useful for you as well. [TouchCustoms](http://github.com/eisernWolf/TouchCustoms) There is more inside that described. Never had a good chance to write documentation for every small detail.